# Sketch: Apply a bitmap mask to a group of vectors

Tags: sketch-app

Is this something that's possible? "Use a mask" is disabled over a group of vectors.

Example:

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 1):

Choose the bitmap only. Then 'use as mask' will be clickable. In your screenshot you've clicked on both the bitmap and the group of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

AFAIK, You could do that only by combining all those vectors into single vector and apply mask to it.